# I want to auto checked some checkboxes on the check on one checkbox

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have group of check boxes out of that some are dependent combination. If i check one option box one 1 or 2 other option shouls get auto check and vice versa if unchecked.

```
 this.addUserForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      loginId: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4),Validators.maxLength(20)]],
      name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2),Validators.maxLength(20)]],
      email:  ['',[Validators.required,Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z0-9.-]{1,}@[a-zA-Z.-]{2,}[.]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2,}')]],
      mobile: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern("[0-9]+"), Validators.minLength(10),Validators.maxLength(10)]],
      groupId:['',Validators.required],
      is2FAEnabled: [false,[Validators.required]],
      AccessRights: ['',[Validators.required]]
    });
  }


  onNgModelChange(evt) {

  onSelect(value){
      console.log("value",value)
      if(value == 2){
                console.log("evt2")
                this.addUserForm.get('AccessRights').setValue(1);
      }
  }
```

Not able to achieve this as error comes as 
ERROR TypeError: values.forEach is not a function

Comment: Can you add some more code. or create stackblitz?

Comment: @Chellappan this function have this lines of code only. What else you want me to add?

Comment: Have not you created form group?

Comment: @Chellappan added

Answer (score 0):

Take an idea from this example

**component.html**

```
<mat-selection-list #access (selectionChange)="onSelection($event, access.selectedOptions.selected)" >
  <mat-list-option *ngFor="let access of typesOfAccess" [value]='access' [selected]="access.checked">
    {{access.name}} 
  </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

**Component.ts**

```
 typesOfAccess = [{"name":"credit","checked":false},{"name":"sales","checked":true},{"name":"ops","checked":false},{"name":"bst","checked":false}];

  onSelection(e, v) { 
    this.typesOfAccess[3].checked = !this.typesOfAccess[3].checked;
    console.error(this.typesOfAccess[3].checked);
  }
```

Play around this

[DEMO / EXMAMPLE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-selection-mvkrfr)

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectedOptions' of undefined

Comment: HI @Anil , this is working but i want some more combination like on click of 1 ,2 should get select , on 4 -7, on 8-5 like that.
With your code in 11 check box , i am able to check only 1 and 2.

Comment: @ShripadAvhad ; Idea is to create list of objects having one key as boolean which will tell checked or unchecked boxes.